# Random results from a Goroutine channel which receives a pointer to an underlying object

Tags: go

I just start learning GO. I am trying to receive an object but want to update it via a pointer to the underlying object. But the code doesn't work correctly, can someone tell me how to fix it?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type JSONStr struct {
    str []byte
    err error
}

type person struct {
    First string
    Last  string
    Age   int
}

func test(ch chan *JSONStr) {

    t := <-ch

    p1 := person{
        First: "James",
        Last:  "Bond",
        Age:   32,
    }

    p2 := person{
        First: "Miss",
        Last:  "Moneypenny",
        Age:   27,
    }

    people := []person{p1, p2}
    fmt.Println(people)
    t.str, t.err = json.Marshal(people)
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan *JSONStr)
    var result JSONStr
    go test(ch)
    ch <- &result
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

[Link to Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PNr9ucGHbrB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you print `result`, it may not have been mutated by `test` yet. One simple way to solve this is to pass use two channels like so:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type JSONStr struct {
    str []byte
    err error
}

func (j JSONStr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("str=%s, err=%s", j.str, j.err)
}

type person struct {
    First string
    Last  string
    Age   int
}

func test(in <-chan bool, out chan<- *JSONStr) {
    <-in

    people := []person{
        {First: "James", Last: "Bond", Age: 32},
        {First: "Miss", Last: "Moneypenny", Age: 27},
    }
    fmt.Println(people)

    b, err := json.Marshal(people)
    out <- &JSONStr{str: b, err: err}
}

func main() {
    in, out := make(chan bool), make(chan *JSONStr)
    go test(in, out)
    in <- true
    result := <-out
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

EDIT: Returning a pointer from a function is safe and idiomatic in Go. From Effective Go:

> Note that, unlike in C, it's perfectly OK to return the address of a local variable; the storage associated with the variable survives after the function returns. In fact, taking the address of a composite literal allocates a fresh instance each time it is evaluated

Comment: Thanks. That surely works but are you creating a pointer from the heap which is allocated within a function? Is it a safe way to do it?

Comment: Yes! In Go it is safe and very common to do this.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your clarification. I made some changes based on your response https://play.golang.org/p/R2wzPrUxfnN